# Determining maxima and minima of the function $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{1+2\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the next function $f(x)=\dfrac{\cos x}{1+2\sqrt{x}}$.

I want to find the maxima and minima of the function.

The derivative of this function is $$f'(x)= \frac{-(\sqrt{x}\cdot \sin x+2x\cdot \sin x+ \cos x)}{\sqrt{x}\cdot (1+2\sqrt{x})^2}$$

Then I get the next equation that I have trouble with solving it.
$$(2x+\sqrt{x})\sin x+ \cos x=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The global maximum is $1$. This can easily be seen by noting that a ratio is maximised by maximising the numerator whilst minimising the denominator. The function is only defined for non-negative real $x$. The numerator has a maximum of $1$ which occurs at $x=0$. At this value, $\sqrt x$ also reaches its minimum value of $0$. Hence the global maximum is $\frac{\cos 0}{1 + \sqrt 0} = 1$.

If you plot the curve, you will notice its "sinusoidal" behaviour with an irregular period. There are an infinite number of local maxima and minima, but that equation involving setting the derivative to zero is not amenable to an exact solution. Numerical methods must be used.

(You've worked out the derivative correctly, by the way).